# PHP function, calling from another file error with variable

Tags: php, function

I have a functions.php file with the following content.

```
function maxSavePerHour($ip, $maxSave = 15){
//DB connection and query. Working fine.
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($totalRows <=$maxSave){
        $safe=true;
    }else{
        $safe=false;
    }

if($safe){
    echo "OK";
}else{
    echo "Not OK";
}
}
```

I call that function from another page. And I use the function as following.

```
maxSavePerHour($ip, 5);
```

If I change the value the function echoes text as it should.
The problem is the     $safe variable. If I echo $safe i get nothing.

Any clues?
The reason I need $safe to be true or false is because I use it in a if statement later.

I put global $safe;` and now its working. Thanks Nile.

Comment: i am unable to see any function definition and what do you mean by: "i call that function from another page"?

Comment: you may need to put `global $safe` at the beginning of your function, but I couldn't know without seeing the whole thing.

Comment: Very unclear question, please show more code context and *where* you output the `$safe` variable. Spontaneous guess: variable scope!

Comment: What if you ``var_dump($safe)`` ?

Comment: @Nile No, he does *not* need to put `global` anywhere.

Comment: @harald - well, there is a stray brace at the end of the code, so I guess there probably is a function declaration up there. Don't know why he hasn't included it though; the question can't be answered properly without it.

Comment: Sorry, I cut out some DB info up there and the function declaration got erased too.

Comment: Also, I would usually take this opportunity to point out that the `mysql_xx()` functions are deprecated and not recommended for use. See the PHP manual for more info. You should be switching to use the `mysqli_xx()` alternatives or PDO library instead.

Comment: please echo $maxSave and what you get please check it.

Comment: I put global $safe;` and now its working. Thanks Nile.

Comment: @user1204032, instead of making it global, pass it through an argument in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to simply return $safe and handle it from the other file. Or better yet, implement the following:

```
function maxSavePerHour($ip, $maxSave = 15){
//DB connection and query. Working fine.
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($totalRows <=$maxSave){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

You do not actually need a $safe variable.
Marking your $safe variable as global is a very bad idea and should hardly ever be done.

Comment: From where you call the method you can do something of this sort: if(maxSavePerHour('valuesfor$ip', 15)){//true} else {//false} or $ok = maxSavePerHour('valuesfor$ip', 15); if($ok){//do something} else {//do someething else}

Answer (score 1):

If you echo $safe, it is echoing nothing because $safe is a boolean value (and false will not echo a value, whereas true will echo 1). I would return the value of $safe and then change the calling code to handle this. E.g.:

```
function maxSavesPerHour($ip, $maxSave) {
  $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
  return ( $totalRows <= $maxSave ? TRUE : FALSE );
}
```

Then call it from your code like this:

```
if ( maxSavesPerHour($ip, 5) ) {
  //do something when true
} else {
 //do something when false
}
```

Comment: I don't think the boolean value is a problem, but this is the only answer with sensible code. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
function maxSavePerHour($ip, $maxSave = 15){
//DB connection and query. Working fine.
$totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res);
    if($totalRows <=$maxSave){
        $safe=true;
    }else{
        $safe=false;
    }

    if($safe){
        echo "OK";
    }else{
        echo "Not OK";
    }
    return $safe;
}
$safe = maxSavePerHour($ip, 5);
echo $safe;
```

Comment: boolean are not really well showed with `echo` better use `var_dump`

Answer (score 0):

```
function maxSavePerHour($ip, $maxSave = 15){ 
    //DB connection and query. Working fine. 
    $totalRows = mysql_num_rows($res); 
    $safe = false;
    if($totalRows <=$maxSave){ 
         $safe=true; 
    }else{ 
         $safe=false; 
    } 

    if($safe){ 
        echo "OK"; 
    }else{ 
        echo "Not OK"; 
    } 
}
```

safe only exsists in the if not outside it

Comment: @mithunsatheesh I was on a mobile phone so I couldn't format it, thanks :)